# NPM Package Directory Mess

Tags: json, node.js, gruntjs, npm

While ago when I run `npm install` under my project it installed all node modules correctly and nicely by installing all packages that I have defined under `packages.json` file.

Now that I have updated `npm` and `node` to latest version and when I run `npm install` 90% of sub directories of npm packages will be installed under `node_modules` folder. Thus it will look so messy. Here's the picture of the folders: (I couldn't get all the folders since resolution is limited)

[image]

and here's my `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "my-application",
  "description": "description here...",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": ""
  },
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-autoprefixer": "~0.4.0",
    "grunt-bower-install": "~0.7.0",
    "grunt-concurrent": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-connect-proxy": "~0.2.0",
    "grunt-connect-socket.io": "^0.7.1",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "~0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-coffee": "~0.7.0",
    "grunt-contrib-compass": "~1.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "~0.3.0",
    "grunt-contrib-connect": "~0.11.2",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "~0.7.0",
    "grunt-contrib-htmlmin": "~0.1.3",
    "grunt-contrib-imagemin": "~0.3.0",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.7.1",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.2.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.5.2",
    "grunt-fixmyjs": "0.2.0",
    "grunt-google-cdn": "~0.2.0",
    "grunt-karma": "~0.6.2",
    "grunt-newer": "~0.5.4",
    "grunt-ngmin": "~0.0.2",
    "grunt-rev": "~0.1.0",
    "grunt-usemin": "~2.0.0",
    "jasmine": "~2.3.1",
    "jshint-stylish": "~0.1.3",
    "jshint-stylish-ex": "^0.2.0",
    "karma": "~0.10.8",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~0.1.1",
    "karma-coffee-preprocessor": "~0.1.1",
    "karma-firefox-launcher": "~0.1.2",
    "karma-html2js-preprocessor": "~0.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~0.1.5",
    "karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor": "~0.1.0",
    "karma-ng-scenario": "~0.1.0",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "~0.1.1",
    "karma-requirejs": "~0.2.0",
    "karma-script-launcher": "~0.1.0",
    "load-grunt-tasks": "~0.2.0",
    "requirejs": "~2.1.9",
    "socket.io": "~1.3.7",
    "socket.io-client": "^1.3.7",
    "time-grunt": "~0.2.1"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.8.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "grunt test"
  }
}
```

How I can tell to `npm` to install/arrange directories properly?

NPM version: 3.5.0
Node version: 5.1.0

I use grunt to run the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [`npm 3`](http://dailyjs.com/2015/06/26/npm-3/) your dependencies will now be installed flat - by default. If possible, all of your dependencies, and their dependencies, and their dependencies will be installed in your project's node_modules folder without nesting. Nesting will only occur when two or more modules have conflicting dependencies.

This was done because in windows there's restriction on maximum path length.

Comment: Thanks Kunal for the answer. It seems this is one of the new features of that version.